# GCM creating Duclicate multiple Notifications from server

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

This seems a known issue, but when i searched everyone talking about duplicate creation of GCM registration ids. But i doesn't have duplicate IDS  still i am getting duplicates some times it will be 3 some time 10, its not constant.I am not able to understand why.

Following is My code.

Server Side:

I am Storing Registarion ids in DB and whenever ID for a perticular user changes i am updating the column of table. So I dont have multiple Id for a single user.

```
          if(conn!=null)
          {

           PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT regid from userlogin1");
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                list.add(rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
```

From this i am selecting different Id's

```
           for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)

            {
            String regId = list.get(i).toString();
            System.out.println(regId);
            String userMessage = request.getParameter("message");
            Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
            Message message = new Message.Builder().collapseKey("Gcm").timeToLive(30)
                    .delayWhileIdle(false).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, userMessage).build();

            result = sender.send(message, regId, 1);
            request.setAttribute("pushStatus", result.toString());

            }
```

By this i am pushing the Messages.

My list Contains 2 elements as I have 2 users in DB.

When I check at BrodcastReceiver it always getting multiple times invocation.
Due to which i am getting duplicated notification of same message.

I tried delayWhileIdle setting true still same.
Please help

Comment: Are you receiving multiple notifications on both devices? Also could you try sending to a single device and see if you get the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately GSM Sometimes behaves abnormally so i have a solution I know its not the best Solution but M sure it will solve your problem. Once i had the same issue i avoid this by creating an identifier like. if i receive message A. I mark identifier as A it means identifier has a message A and when ever i receive another A message (Which is Duplicate) i simply compare with my identifier if they are same i just ignore the message otherwise i process further...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but how can i do that, i have chances that i might get a repetitive message content like room number, if it comes at a different time then how can i achieve what u suggested

Comment: ok.. one room can only be assigned to one person at a time.. when another room is assigned then identifier should also change like 1st time it is 1 then it will be 2.. then it can be 1 again and vise versa... hope u understand